# source currently evaluates to an error excel

Tags: excel

**I have two workbooks:**

- `Source.xlsx`
- `Book1.xlsm`

The data in `Book1.xlsm` is linked to the `Source.xlsx` via a drop down box in `Book1.xlsm` reading data from `Source.xlsx`.

In `Source.xlsx` the column `I` referring is `Column C`. with defined name of `Branch`

In `Book1.xlsm` I define the name `BT` and refers to `Source.xlsx!Branch`
And data validation it to `=BT`

Everything runs well until I save, close and reopen it, the error message shows up "source currently evaluates to an error Excel, do you want to continue?"

Where have I gone wrong?

---

**EDIT:** I realised that if my `Source.xlsx` is not open up together with my file, `Book1.xlsm` drop down list doesn't work Any suggestion on this?

Excel version 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that it can't find the file once the target is no longer open.

You can **add the path to the filename** in the formula.

For example instead of:

```
=Source.xlsx!Branch!$A$1
```

you would use:

```
='c:\pathToYourFile\[Source.xlsx]Branch'!$A$1
```

You can learn more about external cell references at [this link](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f) and [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa).

Comment: Hi i did have the path linked however its still unable to work

Answer (score 0):

**Solve: Remove space from your header and use underscore(_).** 
wallahu aalam